# $.Ajax return data - unable to find() & inject specific div contents

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, oop, find

## The task

My page has 3 groups of 'panels' which I intend to grab the html for via AJAX from 3 separate pages.

Each page that I'm grabbing has div's denoted by data-id, which the panels in a group they correspond to.

The pages that host the HTML to be injected are fully qualified html pages (so that they can potentially be indexed by robots for good SEO, though I intend to find some way of redirecting any traffic to them via mod_rewrite rules to the actual site which really is a one-page site.)

I've built a class called AjaxFetcher with the intention that the first time it has its fetch() method called, it'll fetch the content and store it in a variable. Then if called again, can just use the data in the stored variable.

The ajax success(result) method, stores $(result) in the this.fullContents and then calls a second method in the object "process".

In process, if I just call `$('#events .panel-1 .overlayContent').html(this.fullContents)`, I get the full HTML that was returned by the ajax request inserted into my panel.

However, I want to search through the returned result and get just that panels contents.

### The problem

Putting the result of
    `this.fullContents.find('[data-id="'+mypanel'+"]');` into the html() function, nothing is inserted.

I've tried finding the div by id too, using this.fullContents.contents() I was able to retrieve just the body of the returned document and the image urls didn't break either, but using .find() on it, I'm still unable to get that specific div.

If I console.log the result of this.fullContent or the result of `this.fullContent.find('[data-id="'+panel+'"]');`, I get `[object Object]` so presumably something is being returned??

This method has worked before in the past for me, though this is my first time trying to encapsulate the function in a class that I can use several times, rather than just once. I can't help but feel there something fundamental to classes, or the scope of this that I'm missing.

Bear in mind the code below is unfinished. The ajax call is inside an if statement re:not being called again, but hasnt had the else part completed.

Furthermore, the html inject function should be actually look something more like:
`this.section.find('[data-id="'+panel+'"]').html(toInject)` etc..

### Code

My ajax fetching class is as follows:

```
var cosy = cosy || {};

cosy.AjaxFetcher = function(options) {
    /*Options*/
    this.hasFetched = false;
    this.fullContents = null;
    this.section = $(options.section) || null;
    this.sectionName = options.section || null;
    this.toReturn = null;
    this.fetchUrl = 'content/' + options.section.replace("#", "") + '.html';
    console.log("url:" + this.fetchUrl);
}

cosy.AjaxFetcher.prototype = {
    init: function() {

    },
    fetch: function(panel) {
        var returnMe;
        var that = this;
        if (!this.hasFetched) {
            $.ajax({
                processData: true,
                async: false,
                type: 'GET',
                beforeSend: function() {

                },
                complete: function() {

                },
                error: function() {
                    /*manual page load*/
                    console.log("AJAX error");
                },
                success: function(result) {
                    console.log("ajax success");
                    that.fullContents = $(result);
                    that.hasFetched = true;
                    that.process(panel);
                },
                url: this.fetchUrl
            });
        } else {

        }
    },
    process: function(panel) {
        var toInject = this.fullContents.find('[data-id="'+panel+'"]');
        $('#events .panel-1 .overlayContent').html(toInject);
    }
}
```

I call this from within my main code currently as:

`var ajaxTest = new cosy.AjaxFetcher({section: '#events'});
        ajaxTest.fetch('weddings');`

The page im fetching the data from (`<html> and <head>` tags ommitted):

```
<body>
    <div class="introText">
        <h3>Events</h3>
        <p>From source of produce to presentation of plate we’re passionate about what we do and everything on our menus is produced here in our own kitchen.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="panel" data-id="weddings">
        <div class="scrollWrapper">
            <div class="imgWrapper">
                <img src="content/assets/events/fish.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="contentCopyWrapper">
                <div class="contentCopy">
                    <h3 class="title">Weddings</h3>
                    <div class="copy"<p>Reception drinks, canapés and our Three Course Menu are the perfect choice for your celebration.</p>
                    <p>Whether a garden marquee or a stately home, Kitchen of Kent can take care of all your needs allowing you to enjoy your special day.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel" data-id="festivals">

    </div>
    <div class="panel" data-id="etcetcetc">

    </div>
    <div class="panel">

    </div>
    <div class="panel">

    </div>
    <div class="panel">

    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: That code needs rethinking. You've done a lot of work to create a handy class, and all you've ended up with is synchronous ajax calls ?

Comment: As I said in the beggining, its just a foundation to build the class with. The class seemed like a sensible way of storing the functionality outside of the main code and to store the results so that they could be accessed again & again for further panels and used again for other sections. Asides, I wanted to practice building classes

Comment: And it's a good idea, but you should return promises and use more jQuery